# What does that script mean? What do i have to do to run it?

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, firmware

So, i have to update a firmware of a sonoff switch with a script i found on GitHub, i don't know how and where to run it, what programmes do i need. (I'm on windows)

I installed bash and tried to run it but it says "No such file or directory" and none of the tutorials on the internet works.
it says "line 8: esptool.py command not found"

```
esptool.py \
            -p $SONOFF_PORT \
            --baud 115200 \
            write_flash \
            -fs 8m \
            -fm dout \
            -ff 40m \
            0x0 ./firmware/rboot.bin \
            0x1000 ./firmware/blank_config.bin \
            0x2000 ./firmware/Sonoff_$POWERON_STATE.bin
```

it should work and start the script but i keep getting error messages.

Answer (score 0):

**To install esptool using pip `pip install esptool`.**

To check if you have python or pip installed:

```
python -V
pip -V
```

Comment: You might need `python -m pip --version` to check the version of pip.

Answer (score 0):

According to the filename (`esptool.py`) this should be a `python` script. So you need to have the correct python version (`python2` or `python3`) installed and then run it via the respective python interpreter.

```
python esptool.py ...
```

Just executing it via bash tries to interpret as a bash script and that explains the error you are getting.

Comment: where i have to install esptool from? i installed python latest version

Comment: I am not aware of this tool `esptool`. if it is a package found in standard python repositories, as one option, you can install it via `pip`: `pip install esptool`. But for that, you need to have `pip` also installed. (this is installed by default in `python3`). Just check `pip -v`, it should return current `pip` version if it is installed.